# Do I need to put the 'return' statement inside a 'casper.then' block for the parent function to wait for the child function to complete execution?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Sample 1:

```
function abc(){
    // code1 takes 5 secs to execute;
    // code2 takes 1 sec to execute;
});

casper.then(function(){
    abc();

    casper.then(function(){
        console.log("All statements inside abc functions have been executed");
    });
});
```

I have observed that casperjs initiates the next statement as soon as it has initiated the first statement unless we use `casper.then()`. So in the above code, code2 gets initiated without waiting for code1 to complete execution.

My question is whether the control will return back to the calling function as soon as code2 is initiated or will it wait for function abc() to **complete** executing all statements. Please note that there is a `casper.then()` in the calling function just after the call to abc().

In case it doesn't wait for code1 to complete, can I do this:
Sample 2:

```
function abc(){
    // code1 takes 5 secs to execute;
    // code2 takes 1 sec to execute;

    casper.then(function(){
        return;
    });
});

casper.then(function(){
    abc();

    casper.then(function(){
        console.log("All statements inside abc functions have been executed");
    });
});
```

**I want the console.log() to be executed only after all the statements inside abc() have been completely executed.**

Comment: As I said in my answer `casper.then(function(){ return; });` really does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what `code1` and `code2` are. If it is completely synchronous code, which I doubt, because you asked the question, you can use `then` after that:

```
function abc(){
    // code1 takes 5 secs to execute;
    // code2 takes 1 sec to execute;
});

casper.then(function(){
    abc();

    casper.then(function(){
        console.log("All statements inside abc functions have been executed");
    });
});
```

If it is not synchronous, you need to set some global variable to a *finish* value in the complete (or however it might be named) callback. You then [`waitFor`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor) its execution:

```
var globalObj = {};
function abc(){
    // code1 takes 5 secs to execute and sets globalObj.code1 = true
    // code2 takes 1 sec to execute and sets globalObj.code2 = true
});

casper.then(function(){
    abc();

    // you can wait for the two async calls separately
    casper.waitFor(function check(){
        return (code1 in globalObj) && globalObj.code1;
    }, null, null, 10000);

    casper.waitFor(function check(){
        return (code2 in globalObj) && globalObj.code2;
    }, null, null, 10000);

    // or it can even be combined
    casper.waitFor(function check(){
        return (code1 in globalObj) && globalObj.code1 && (code2 in globalObj) && globalObj.code2;
    }, function then(){
        console.log("All statements inside abc functions have been executed");
        // you can nest more then or other step functions here, 
        // if you only want execution for a successful waitFor
    }, null, 10000);

    // this then is only executed when the waitFor stopped (either because of successful check or because of timeout)
    casper.then(function(){
        console.log("All statements inside abc functions have been executed");
    });
});
```

By the way, an empty `then` block does nothing. It does not help with waiting or anything. You can completely delete this:

```
casper.then(function(){
    return;
});
```

Comment: But I thought all javascript code are asynchronous and so is phantomjs/casperjs. I'm new to the whole javascript and phantomjs. This async style of writing is proving very difficult to properly write code. Are there any conventional pointers on how to write async code is a synchronous manner in casperjs?

Comment: Not all functions are async in javascript or casperjs. If you do [`casper.getCurrentUrl()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getcurrenturl), you will get the current URL synchronously. If you do [`__utils__.sendAJAX`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#sendajax), you can decide if you want it to be async. All `then*` and `wait*` functions are async in that sense that you actually schedule the step to be executed. The beauty of casperjs is that you can chain `then*` and `wait*` so that it reads like synchronous code.

Comment: The underlying phantomjs implementation is not yet updated to use coroutines, but node.js already has them with the `--harmony` flag. With them you might be able to write all async functions in a synchronous manner. I wonder if it is ever going to be supported.

Comment: Yeah, I have been using then* and wait* to make it execute synchronously. But why are `then*` and `wait*` called async functions? They help to write code in a synchronous manner. Shouldn't they be called sync functions?

Comment: They shouldn't be called synchronous, because the function that you provide to them is not executed immediately. Rather, it is scheduled. You can see the strangeness if you have `casper.then(function(){casper.then(function(){this.echo("1");}); this.echo("2");});`, but the output will be 2 and then 1.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can see in the documentation, you should rather declare the then steps next to eachother, rather than inside eachother

so, you should rather use:

```
casper.then(function() {
    abc();
});

casper.then(function() {
    console.log('all statements have been executed');
});
```

see more info: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#then

Comment: You can nest `then` blocks freely and sometimes it is needed. The only thing that needs to be considered is that you shouldn't mix in one function synchronous casper functions and async step functions (which are `then*` and `wait*`).